# Using an parameters as instanced within structure

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, htdp

I am currently completing chapter 7 of the [htdp book](http://htdp.org/) and am trying to create
an instance of the spider structure:

```
#lang racket
;; spider-structure: structure -> ???
;; defines a spider structure with two parameters: legs and volume
(define-struct spider (legs volume))
;; spidercheck: lambda -> num
;; creates a spider check function and determines volume based on legs
(define spidercheck
 (lambda (legs)
  (cond
   ((<= legs 4) 800)
   ((> legs 4) 1000))))
(define a-spider
 (make-spider 4
              (spidercheck ...
```

My problem is that I want to pass the number from `(make-spider 4)` to the `spidercheck` function within the `a-spider` function. I have tried `(spider-legs a-spider)` but of course it says it is used before its definition. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not an entomologist, wouldn't you want `(define (spider? legs) (= legs 8))`? ;)

Comment: @GregHendershott There are 2-legged spiders, too. A certain Peter Parker comes to mind :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic solution would be to call `make-spider` and `spidercheck` with the same parameter, let's say the number `2`:

```
(define spiderman (make-spider 2 (spidercheck 2)))
```

A more interesting alternative would be to define a new function that enforces the restriction that the same `n`, the number of legs, is passed as parameter for both `make-spider` and `spider check`:

```
(define a-spider
  (lambda (n)
    (make-spider n (spidercheck n))))
```

Now, whenever you want to create a spider you can specify just the number of legs as parameter, and let `spidercheck` take care of calculating the volume. Also notice that you can simplify the above snippet even more, using the `define` syntax that makes the `lambda` implicit:

```
(define (a-spider n)
  (make-spider n (spidercheck n)))
```

Either way, to create a new spider (for instance, with `8` legs) do this:

```
(define charlotte (a-spider 8))
```

Comment: Your answer is cleaner. +1

Comment: Yep, I just noticed and fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly. Such a simple, yet powerful solution. Thanks Oscar!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `let` and reusing the number `4` that way.
I'm not too sure how the book is handling spiders but you might need this pattern:

```
(define a-spider
  (let ([a-legs 4])
    (make-spider a-legs (spidercheck a-legs))))
```

This answer is inferior to Oscar's as it hardcodes the number of legs a spider has.  But it does show one way to reference a value multiple times.